# Want to add comment at respective places

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Below is the structure of threaded comments in angular.js form.

```
<form>
<ul class="unstyled">
    <!--  ng-class="{ '{{childcond}}': $index == selectedIndex }"  -->
    <li ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="{{childcond}}"  ng-init=" childcond=checkChild(comment.slug); reply.parentSlug=comment.slug; idstring=slashRemove(comment.slug);" >
        <strong>{{comment.author}}</strong><br>
        <p>
            {{comment.body}}
        </p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="replycomment" >reply</a>
        <div id="{{idstring}}" style="display:none;" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="reply.replyAuthor"><br>
            <span style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" class="hidevalue" ng-model="reply.parentSlug" ng-value="{{comment.slug}}" >
            </span>
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="reply.replyBody"></textarea>
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="reply" ng-click="replyComment(reply,$index)">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When i replying to the comment i am getting my comment in last place.[image]

This is my reply code in angular.js file.

```
$scope.replyComment = function(reply,$index) {
    socket.emit('comment', { author: reply.replyAuthor, 
                             body: reply.replyBody, 
                             parent_slug:reply.parentSlug });

    clearForm();
};
socket.on('comment', function(comment) {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
       console.log(comment);
       $scope.comments.push(comment);
    });
});
```

console.log(comment) gives following structure.

[image]
Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: you give the `$index` param to your 'replycomment' function but don't use it. you should push the comment to a specif child not comments. can you paste your `comments` structure ?

Comment: @AlainIb : I have edited question with comment structure screenshot. $index was simply i was checking something . there is no use of that.

Comment: so to add a comment below a specif comment you use something like `slug:parentslug/currentslug` ?

Comment: @AlainIb this data structure i am inserting in database, thus from mongoose sort query i get comments and its reply as above structure ,But when i reply to a comment its imediately add li element at last as per angular js , if i restart my app , it will come in correct order , but real time its get add in wrong index. I want to correct this.